# convert xml to csv and count on python

Tags: python, xml, csv

the following code converts all the xml data into a csv file

#MY FILE

```
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET
import pandas as pd

tree = ET.parse("file.xml")
root = tree.getroot()

get_range = lambda col: range(len(col))
l = [{r[i].tag:r[i].text for i in get_range(r)} for r in root]

df = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(l)
df.to_csv('file.csv')
```

how can I only select the columns that I want eg i would only like to return 3/10 eg, name, id, address rather than all the info in the tags

Answer (score 0):

You can select only required columns from dataframe like this:

```
df = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(l)
df1 = df[['name', 'id', 'address']]
```

Comment: @Girl007 Please let me know if the answer worked for you?